# Swift 4: Passing data from a collection view cell into another view controller without storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

So this might be a pretty generic question but I am new to working without storyboards.

I am trying to pass data from a collection view cell into another view controller. In the new view controller, I want to show the data that is presented in the collection view cell.

**Home View Controller**

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return games.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let game = games[indexPath.row]
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as? GameCell {

        cell.configureGameCell(game: game)
        return cell
    } else {
        return GameCell()
    }
    return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)

}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

  /*I am able to present the view controller but no data is shown*/

    let game = games[indexPath.row]
    let gameDetailsVC = GameDetailsController()
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: gameDetailsVC)
    present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 130)
}
```

Now, this is the view controller I want to send my data to. The set up isn't exactly identical but I wanted to show that I wanted to take the class that was used to fill the collection view cell and use that same class information to fill my details view controller.

**Details View Controller**

```
class GameDetailsController: UIViewController {

var game: Game!
var location: String!
var gameType" String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    location = game.location
    gameType = game.gameType

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to set the properties of your `GameDetailsController` in your `didSelectItemAt` method.

Comment: FYI - that 3rd `return` statement in your `cellForItemAt` will never be called. And the `if let` is pointless. Just force-cast the first call to `dequeueReusableCell` to your expected cell type.

Comment: Good eye! Return statement must have been left there from an earlier debugging session. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign value to game property of the gameDetailsVC object

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let game = games[indexPath.row]
    let gameDetailsVC = GameDetailsController()
    gameDetailsVC.game = game
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: gameDetailsVC)
    present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!